# Grouping multiple rows from a table into column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two table as below.

Table 1

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | 1.5  | 1.5  | 2.5  |
|    1 | 2.5  | 3.5  | 1.5  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Table 2

```
+------+--------+
| Col1 |  Col2  |
+------+--------+
|    1 |  12345 |
|    1 | 678910 |
+------+--------+
```

I want the result as below.

```
+------+------+------+------+-------+--------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5  |  Col6  |
+------+------+------+------+-------+--------+
|    1 |    4 |    5 |    4 | 12345 | 678910 |
+------+------+------+------+-------+--------+
```

Here Col2, Col3 and Col4 is the aggregate of value from Col2,3,4 in Table 1. And rows from Table 2 are transposed to Columns in the result.

I use Oracle 11G and tried the PIVOT option. But I couldn't aggregate values from Column 2,3,4 in Table 1.

Is there any function available in Oracle which provides direct solution without any dirty work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any limitation on the number of rows in Table2? If not - this means the number of columns in your result is not fixed but will vary depending on the number of rows in the table. Is that your case?

Comment: There is limitation on the number of rows. There will be only 2 rows in Table 2 for a value in Col1.

Answer (score 1):

Since you will always  have only 2 records in second table simple grouping and join will do.
Since I dont have tables I am using CTEs and Inline views

```
with cte1 as (
    select 1 as col1 , 1.5 as col2 , 1.5 as col3, 2.5 as col4 from dual
    union all
    select 1  , 2.5  , 3.5 , 1.5 fom dual
    ) ,
    cte2 as (
    select 1 as col1 , 12345 as col2  fom dual
    union all
    select 1,678910  fom dual )

    select* from( 
    (select col1,sum(col2) as col2 , sum(col3) as col3,sum(col4) as col4
       from cte1 group by col1) as x 
    inner join 
    (select col1  ,min(col2) as col5 ,max(col2) as col from cte2
    group by col1
    ) as y
    on x.col1=y.col1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with
mytab1 as (select col1, col2, col3, col4, 0 col5, 0 col6 from tab1),
mytab2 as
(
    select
        col1, 0 col2, 0 col3, 0 col4, "1_COL2" col5, "2_COL2" col6
    from
        (
            select
                row_number() over (partition by col1 order by rowid) rn, col1, col2
            from
                tab2
        )
    pivot
        (
            max(col2) col2
            for rn in (1, 2)
        )
)
select
    col1,
    sum(col2) col2,
    sum(col3) col3,
    sum(col4) col4,
    sum(col5) col5,
    sum(col6) col6
from
    (
        select * from mytab1 union all select * from mytab2
    )
group by
    col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use the below query

```
with t1 (col1,col2,col3,col4)
as
(
select 1,1.5,1.5,2.5 from dual
union
select 1,2.5,3.5,1.5 from dual

 ),
 t2 (col1,col2)
 as
 (
 select 1,12345 from dual
 union
 select 1,678910 from dual
 )
select * from 
(
select col1
       ,max(decode(col2,12345,12345)) as co5
       ,max(decode(col2,678910,678910)) as col6

from t2
group by col1
) a
inner join
(
 select  col1,sum(col2) as col2,sum(col3) as col3,sum(col4) as col4
 from t1
 group by col1
 ) b
 on a.col1=b.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot only the second table.  You can then do GROUP BY on the nested UNION ALL between table1 (col5 and col6 are null for subsequent group by) and pivoted table2 (col2, col3, col4 are null for subsequent group by).